# Mysql Constraign Database Entries in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, constraints

I am using Mysql 5 and Ruby On Rails 2.3.1. I have some validations that occasionally fail to prevent duplicate items being saved to my database. Is it possible at the database level to restrict a duplicate entry to be created based on certain parameters?

I am saving emails to a database, and don't want to save a duplicate subject line, body, and sender address. Does anyone know how to impose such a limit on a DB through a migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of options to ensure a unique value set is inserted into your table.  Lets consider 1) Push responsibility to the database engine or 2) your application's responsibilitiy.

Pushing responsibility to the database engine could entail the use of creating a UNIQUE index on your table.  See [MySql Create Index syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html).  Note, this solution may result in an exception thrown in case a duplicate value is inserted.  As you've identified what I infer to be three columns to determine uniqueness (subject line, body, and sender address) you'll create the index to include all three columns.  Its been a while since I've worked with Rails so you may want to check the record count inserted as well.

If you desire to push this responsibility to your application software you'll need to contend with potential data insertion conflicts.  That is, assume you have two users creating an email simultaneously (just work with me here) having the same subject line, body, and send address.  Should your code simple query for any records consisting of the text (identical for both users in this example) both will return no records found and will proceed along merily inserting their emails which now violate your premise.  So, you can address this with perhaps a table lock, or some other syncing field in the database to ensure duplicates don't appear.  This latter approach could consist of another table with a single field indicating if someone is inserting a record or not, once completed it updates that record to state it has completed and then others can proceed.

While there you can have a separate architectural discussion on the implications of each alternative I'll leave that to a separate post.  Hopefully this suffices in answering your question.

Comment: You can add the index in rails like this

add_index( :tickets, [:to_email, :body_hash, :subject] , :unique => true, :limit => 255)

note the limit is not part of rails release yet, so you must get this plugin:

http://github.com/eparreno/mysql_index_length

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add a [unique index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) to any columns you want to be unique throughout the table.